# Checkbox JSF - not returning correct value

Tags: java, jsf, checkbox

Here is my problem,

I m using jsf, so my form contain 3 fields
-h:inputText
-h:inputSecret
-h:selectBooleanCheckbox

The beans structure is as follow:

```
    public class  UserBean {

       private CustomerData customer;

public CustomerData getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public CustomerData getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }
}
```

---

```
CustomerBean


public class CustomerData implements Serializable {

  String email = null;
  String password = null;
  Boolean keepLogged = false;

  public CustomerData() {
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public Boolean getKeepLogged() {
    return keepLogged;
  }

  public void setKeepLogged(Boolean keepLogged) {
    this.keepLogged = keepLogged;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }
}
```

So when i submit the form, email and password are exctracted correct but keepLogged stay false no matther if is checked or no.
Any ideas?

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="checkbox" id="remember" value="#{UserBean.customer.keepLogged}" title="#{res.CommonRememberMeTitle}"/>
```

Here is little more code

```
              <h:inputText value="#{UserBean.customer.email}" binding="#{email}" id="email" tabindex="1" maxlength="250">              
              </h:inputText>ck

              <h:inputSecret value="#{UserBean.customer.password}" binding="#{password}" id="password" tabindex="2" maxlength="50" required="true">                      
              </h:inputSecret>
            </span>
```

Comment: Why are you using `Customer` in uppercase and not `customer`?

Comment: spelling mistake, but this is not the problem

Comment: Does 'keepLogged' have the getter and setter methods in CustomerBean? Boolean values' getter's name must be like 'isKeepLogged'.

Comment: @tuxi: The getter is not so relevant for submitting the data, but the setter is definitely present, otherwise OP would have faced a `PropertyNotWritableException`.

Comment: @brakebg: the code posted so far looks fine. Your problem is caused elsewhere. Can you please post the smallest possible `<h:form>` snippet and the method of the command action which we could copy'n'paste'n'run to reproduce exactly the same problem.

Comment: @BalusC - hope this will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

problem is when you change a value of a check box so that new value(changed Value) is not Bind or Set in your bean variable. may be that is your form problem which you have used.

i have one solution for that may be you will like or not.
you can use a:support.

here is my example

if you want to use a ajax support in h:inputText then here is on example

**in XHTML File**

```
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox 
        value="#{UserBean.customerData.keepLogged}">
        <a:support event="onclick" limitToList="true" 
        action="#{UserBean.codeValue(UserBean.customerData.keepLogged)}"/>
 </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

**in Bean File**

```
Class UserBean   

private CustomerData customerData  = new CustomerData ();

public void codeValue(Boolean value){
        info("HERE IS YOUR VALUE : " + value);
        customerData.setKeepLogged(value); 
}
```